# Collection's View Label pass to modal upon tapping the collection view item

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog, popup, collectionview

My problem is I want to pass the label in my collection view to a modal page upon tapping a collection view items.
this is my homepage.xml.cs code:
`

```
  async private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(OrderPageModal);
        }
```

`This is my homepage.xml`

```
 <StackLayout 
                                                    Style="{StaticResource itemsInsideCardViewStackLayoutStyle}">
                                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <Frame 
                                                        Style="{StaticResource stationImageFrameStyle}">
                                                        <Image 
                                                            Style="{StaticResource stationImageStyle}" 
                                                            Source="{Binding ImageURL}" />
                                                    </Frame>
                                                    <StackLayout 
                                                        Style="{StaticResource detailsStackLayout}">
                                                        <Label 
                                                            Text="{Binding storename}" 
                                                            Style="{StaticResource NameLabel}" 
                                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                                            Margin="-40,0,0,0"/>
```

`

that  Text="{Binding storename}" is I get here;( in one file,I just put together my station/store model and the IEnumerable Get().
`

```
 public static IEnumerable<WRSinfo> Get()
        {
            return new List<WRSinfo>
            {

                new WRSinfo()
                {
                    storename="Aqua Refilling Station", status="Open", ImageURL="water_ref.png", distance="2km"

                },
         };
}

  public  string storename { get; set; }
        public string distance { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
```

`

this is my popupmodal page design:
`

```
 <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Green"
                                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                 VerticalOptions="Start"
                                 WidthRequest="100">
                        <Label Text="{Binding storename}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black" x:Name="lblTextStorname" />

                    </StackLayout>
```

`

So what ouput I expect is. If I click collection view item which a name of store, then upon clicking it, a popupmodal will appear then also the name of the store I clicked from collectionview item.
Im newbie to this project and tech, pls help me sir. All comment will be appreciated.

output should be like this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y2Or.png)

Comment: Please do NOT post code as images!  This makes it very difficult to help you

Comment: sorry sir,I will edit it.

Comment: I don’t see a CollectionView anywhere in your code.  If you are using one, using the built in Selection features would make this much easier

Comment: the homepage.xml sir,I just cropped it.
In my collectionview I didnt make any event. that homepage.xml is inside here..

 <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the picture you provide, I recommend you to use the [Xamarin.Forms Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data).

You can change the `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` method to pass the Name of the `WRSinfo` to the SecondPage.

```
  async private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string WRSinfoName = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as WRSinfo).Name;
             await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"SecondPage?name={WRSinfoName}");
        }
```

Then in the SecondPage.xmal.cs you should use the code `[QueryProperty(nameof(Name), "name")]` to accept the data.

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Name), "name")]
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            LoadWRSinfo(value);
        }
    }

    void LoadWRSinfo(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            WRSinfo wRSinfo = WRSinfoData.WRSinfo.FirstOrDefault(a => a.storename== name);
            BindingContext = wRSinfo;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to load. ");
        }
    }    
}
```

This is a sample you can refer to. I am not clear about the data structure you use. So you can follow the sample here the Microsoft provided [Download the sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/Xaminals).